# How to parse unserialized json with python

Tags: python, json, stanford-nlp

I have a JSON response from core NLP and it's like this:

```
text: "Tell me what the notes are for South Australia "
sentence {
  token {
    word: "Tell"
    pos: "VB"
    value: "Tell"
    before: ""
    after: " "
    originalText: "Tell"
  }
  token {
    word: "me"
    pos: "PRP"
    value: "me"
    before: " "
    after: " "
    originalText: "me"
  }
  tokenOffsetBegin: 0
  tokenOffsetEnd: 9
  basicDependencies {
    node {
      sentenceIndex: 0
      index: 1
    }
}
....
```

The important part is to loop through the tokens and get for example word, pos, value, and .... for each token.
this code:

```
    for s in client.annotate("Tell me what the notes are for South Australia"):
        for t in s:
            words.append(t.word)
            gloss.append(t.originalText)
            after.append(t.after)
```

does not work, it says I can't iterate into the JSON output cuz it's not all the same type, what can I do?

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: I'll bet `pycorenelp` has a parser for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not JSON. It's obvious since:

```
text: "Tell me what the notes are for South Australia "
sentence {
....
```

This will throw a error if it actually is. Fix it like this:

```
question {
  text: "Tell me what the notes are for South Australia "
  sentence {
  ....
}
```

or something else. Whatever, this is not JSON.

Comment: I know its not JSON but it says it returns JSON whay should i do?

Comment: it's not a single data that I fix it server generates this data

Comment: Just change the addition of the jquery.